# Mapping nested of nested json in pojo using spring boot with Jackson

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, pojo, jackson-databind

[image: here is my json structure but i hv not able to mapping with pojo in spring boot because in this case nested of nested mapping is need]

How to mapg nested json in spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

You can use online json to java pojo generators online by pasting your json there and select language and datatypes and done.

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to send the json data in a post request to the api endpoint.

You can simply map any nested json structure into java pojo class.

In your example you have an array of objects.

So let me explain you with a similar example. Lets consider the following json data for simplicity sake.

```
[
  {
    "property1": "value1",
    "array": [
      {
        "property2": "value2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So first lets create a dao class to map this object.

We need to create 2 classes.

1. NestedObject.java

```
package com.example.demo.nested;

import java.util.List;

public class NestedObject {
    private final String property1;

    private final List<Property> array;

    public NestedObject() {
        this.property1 = null;
        this.array = null;
    }

    public NestedObject(String property1, List<Property> array) {
        this.property1 = property1;
        this.array = array;
    }

    public String getProperty1() {
        return property1;
    }

    public List<Property> getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NestedObject{" +
                "property1='" + property1 + '\'' +
                ", array=" + array +
                '}';
    }
}
```

2. Property.java

```
package com.example.demo.nested;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Property {
    private final String property2;

    public Property() {
        this.property2 = null;
    }

    public Property(String property2) {
        this.property2 = property2;
    }

    @JsonProperty("property2")
    public String getProperty2() {
        return property2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Property{" +
                "property2='" + property2 + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add the no arg constructors!

Now the controller

3. Controller.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.nested.NestedObject;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class Controller {
    @PostMapping("/")
    public List<NestedObject> post(@RequestBody List<NestedObject> request) {
        System.out.println(request);
        return request;
    }
}
```

This worked for me. Please try it and let me know if this works for you.